# Does anyone tries to call o return a Diagram view?

Tags: odoo-10, odoo, odoo-view

I'm trying to return a Diagram view but I got an Access Error, I'm using Odoo .v10:

[image: AccessError]

But my user has the proper access permission, even with the admin user I got the same access error.

This is my code:

ir.model.access.csv

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink 
access_montecarlo_project,montecarlo.project,model_montecarlo_project,group_montecarlo_user,1,1,1,1
access_montecarlo_sprint,montecarlo.sprint,model_montecarlo_sprint,group_montecarlo_user,1,1,1,1
access_montecarlo_activity,montecarlo.activity,model_montecarlo_activity,group_montecarlo_user,1,1,1,1
access_montecarlo_activity_transition,montecarlo.activity.transition,model_montecarlo_activity_transition,group_montecarlo_user,1,1,1,1
access_montecarlo_project_result,montecarlo.project.result,model_montecarlo_project_result,group_montecarlo_user,1,1,1,1
```

My .py code to return the the diagram view, in a button type object, and action too:

```py
@api.multi
def show_diagram(self):
    # TODO: Create a group with the permisitions to montecarlo.sprint to the user of
    # that group can see the diagram view
    self.ensure_one()

    view_mode = 'diagram'
    view_diagram_id = self.env.ref('montecarlo.montecarlo_sprint_diagram_view').id
    res_id = False
    domain = [('id','=',self.id)]
    context = {}

    return {
        'name': u"Activities",
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_mode': view_mode,
        'res_model': 'montecarlo.sprint',
        'target': 'self',
        'views': [(view_diagram_id, 'diagram')],
        'view_id': view_diagram_id,
        'res_id': res_id,
        'domain': domain,
        'context': context,
    }
```

And this is the console log when I press my button:

```
2018-01-18 02:10:10,807 14185 INFO montecarlo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2018 02:10:10] "POST /web/dataset/call_button HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2018-01-18 02:10:10,850 14185 WARNING montecarlo odoo.models: montecarlo.sprint.read() with unknown field 'activity_to_id'
2018-01-18 02:10:10,852 14185 WARNING montecarlo odoo.models: montecarlo.sprint.read() with unknown field 'duration'
2018-01-18 02:10:10,852 14185 WARNING montecarlo odoo.models: montecarlo.sprint.read() with unknown field 'activity_from_id'
2018-01-18 02:10:10,854 14185 INFO montecarlo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2018 02:10:10] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/montecarlo.sprint/read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2018-01-18 02:10:10,882 14185 INFO montecarlo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2018 02:10:10] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/montecarlo.sprint/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2018-01-18 02:10:10,920 14185 INFO montecarlo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2018 02:10:10] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2018-01-18 02:10:10,931 14185 INFO montecarlo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2018 02:10:10] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/montecarlo.activity/read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Let me know if you need more details of my code.

EDIT:

This is the .py models:

```
class Sprint(models.Model):
    _name='montecarlo.sprint'

    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)
    activities_ids = fields.One2many('montecarlo.activity', 'sprint_id', string='Activities')
    project_id = fields.Many2one('montecarlo.project', 'Project', required=True)


class Activity(models.Model):
    _name='montecarlo.activity'

    name = fields.Char('Short Name')
    duration = fields.Integer('Duration(weeks)',
                          help='Duration of the activity, on weeks.', required=True)
    start = fields.Boolean('Start', help="This activity is the root of the Sprint.", index=True)
    sprint_id = fields.Many2one('montecarlo.sprint', 'Sprint Name')
    from_ids = fields.One2many('montecarlo.activity.transition', 'activity_to_id', string='Previous Activities')
    to_ids = fields.One2many('montecarlo.activity.transition', 'activity_from_id', string='Next Activities')


class ActivityTransition(models.Model):
     _name='montecarlo.activity.transition'

    name = fields.Char('Description')
    activity_from_id = fields.Many2one('montecarlo.activity', 'Previous Activity', required=True, ondelete="cascade")
    activity_to_id = fields.Many2one('montecarlo.activity', 'Next Activity', required=True, ondelete="cascade")
```

And this is the Diagram view xml:

```
    <!-- Sprint Diagram View -->
    <record id="montecarlo_sprint_diagram_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">montecarlo.sprint.diagram.view</field>
        <field name="model">montecarlo.sprint</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <diagram string="Project Editor">
                <node object="montecarlo.activity" bgcolor="gray:start==True">
                    <field name="name" />
                    <field name="duration" />
                </node>
                <arrow object="montecarlo.activity.transition" source="activity_from_id" destination="activity_to_id" label="['name']">
                    <field name="activity_from_id" />
                    <field name="activity_to_id" />
                </arrow>
            </diagram>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you edit the question and add code for the fields of montecarlo.sprint model?

Comment: Sure @AtulArvind.